# Can A and B be functionaly dependent on each other?

Tags: database, database-normalization, functional-dependencies

If B is functionally dependent on A (A -> B) can A be functionally dependent on B (B -> A)? Why?

Example:

A table contains five columns: Patient Number, Full name, Bed number, Ward number and Ward name.

Is it possible to say that Ward Number -> Ward Name and Ward Name -> Ward Number?

From my understanding a functional dependency A -> B means that given a tuple containing A there will always be the same B, but not the other way around.

A Ward will always have the same number and name making the functional dependency go both ways.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If B is functionally dependent on A (A -> B) can A be functionally dependent on B (B -> A)?

Yes. Informally, it might help you to think about it this way.

Say a relation has two candidate keys, A and B. Since A is a candidate key, it determines all the other attributes. So A->B. And since B is a candidate key, it also determines all the other attributes. So B -> A.

For a real-world example, think about a table of chemical elements. (WARNING: I'm not a chemist.)

```
element_name  atomic_number  chem_symbol
--
Hydrogen      1              H
Helium        2              He
Lithium       3              Li
...
```

Each of these three columns is a candidate key. And `element_name` determines `atomic_number` and `chem_symbol`, `atomic_number` determines `element_name`, and `chem_symbol`, etc.